# Use "readonly record struct" type as the out parameter of method, will it cause boxing?

Tags: c#

Consider the following code, I use this to parse data streams in some performance-critical places. In this case, will the `message` be boxed?

```cs
readonly record struct DataMessage(ulong Number, string Str, 
                                   ReadOnlySequence<byte> Payload);

bool TryParseMessage(ref ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer, 
                     out DataMessage message) {
    message = default;
    ...
    message = new DataMessage(...);
    return true;
}

void PerformanceCriticalFunction() {
    ...
    while (TryParseMessage(..., out var message)) {
        // consume the message
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, I don't think so. `readonly record struct` is just a fancy struct. The `out` parameter doesn't matter for boxing, nullable doesn't perform boxing on its own, and you don't do it anywhere. Still, it is a bit weird to do nullable out, what is the point? You return bool from the method to determine whether it is set or not, right?

Comment: @freakish Yes, if `TryParseMessage` return `false`, that means the `message` is not available. In other words, the `ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer` has not enough data to parse as `DataMessage`.

Comment: @freakish I found that I can remove the nullable `?` of `DataMessage`. I edited my origin question. My brain exploded.

Comment: @huang the `?` here is `Nullable<T>` since the compiler knows that `DataMessage` is a `struct`; `Nullable<T>` *also* does not involve boxing

Comment: @huang yes, in your scenario `?` potentially adds unneeded overhead only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is nothing here that relates to boxing. Boxing is caused by any of the following:

- converting a value-type to `object` directly (or `dynamic`, which is just `object` with an accent, or `ValueType` - which sounds ironic)
- converting a value-type to an interface that it implements (outside of "constrained call", which is ... complex to explain but *mostly* comes down to `<T> where T : ISomeInterface`)
- calling a `virtual` method that is *not overridden* on a value-type (this also relates to "constrained call" rules if the type is in a different assembly)
- using the struct as the target of a delegate
- (probably some other niche things I'm forgetting)

None of these things apply, so... no boxing

If in doubt: [test it](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) - there are no `box` instructions emitted. If we deliberately add a `GC.KeepAlive(message)` (in my case in `TryParseMessage`) to look for *expected* boxing, we see something similar to:

```
    IL_0023: ldarg.2
    IL_0024: ldobj DataMessage
    IL_0029: box DataMessage
    IL_002e: call void [System.Runtime]System.GC::KeepAlive(object)
```

which tells you what you're looking for